# Start Without Debugging is disabled in Monodevelop

Tags: mono

I tried to start C#-programming in Ubuntu. I installed MonoDevelop 7.8.2 but when I tried to run the program, the option "Start Without Debugging" is disabled. Is this a bug in MonoDevelop? Is there a workaround for this issue?